# How to handle default margin in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC project. when trying to add a cover poster to the page, getting some margin in two sides. I tried several codes to get the image in full width, but it doesn't work.

what I tried,

This is my full html and css.

```css
    .cover {
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133633/pexels-photo-133633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
/*section {
    margin-left: -115px;
    margin-right: -115px;
}*/
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<section>
    <div class="cover img-fluid"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I suppose you have tried this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp
if this doesn't work please provide some html code.

Comment: I have tried this css properties already (you can see in the question).

Comment: Alright I see, well can you provide us with html and css u have at the moment so we can try and error for our self. Its hard to know whats wrong if we don't have code

Comment: <section>
    <div class="cover img-fluid"></div>
</section>

Comment: Seems to work fine with the code you have provided, please could you edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: The question edited please take a look.

Comment: By default `site.css` added in the `layout page` and inside this CSS it uses `margin and padding`. Step 1) `Remove it from layout page`. Step 2) `Set margin and padding to 0`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using bootstrap this snippet can't run your code correctly **(Next time tell in your question that you use bootstrap)**. But what i found out when u showed the code with the cards. You didn't work in the section. if you want you image to be the background and work on that image. Then you have to work in the `div` or in this case `section`. Try the HTML code below that should work.

```css
.cover {
 background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/133633/pexels-photo-133633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 }


body{
    margin:0;
    padding-top:0px;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="cover img-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 card mycard mt-5">
            <div class="card-img img-fluid text-center myimg">
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iAhcp6m_91O-ClK79h8EQQHaFj%26pid%3DApi%26h%3D160&f=1" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-4 card mycard mt-5">
            <div class="card-img img-fluid text-center myimg">
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iAhcp6m_91O-ClK79h8EQQHaFj%26pid%3DApi%26h%3D160&f=1" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-4 card mycard mt-5">
            <div class="card-img img-fluid text-center myimg">
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iAhcp6m_91O-ClK79h8EQQHaFj%26pid%3DApi%26h%3D160&f=1" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-4 card mycard mt-5">
            <div class="card-img img-fluid text-center myimg">
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iAhcp6m_91O-ClK79h8EQQHaFj%26pid%3DApi%26h%3D160&f=1" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The height of the image is changed. but width is same, no change.

Comment: Then you must have added some css code that is overriding the class .cover.

Comment: section {
    margin-left: -115px;
    margin-right: -115px;
}       This code gives what i want. but as you can see here i am using negative ratios. Is it a good practice using negative fixed values for a responsive site?

Comment: In my codepen the `margin-left` and `margin-right` are making the page bigger and since your picture is 100vh and not bigger it doesn't fill the extra space. Try removing the `margin-left` and `margin-right`. Out of curiousity what is that code used for?

Comment: For getting full width image, i just tried this. Like you said some of my css code overriding the class .cover how can i fix this.

Comment: Please do me a favour and update your question and copy paste `ALL` your html and css code. `DON'T` forget to remove all important information like personal stuff

Comment: full html and css are provided.

Answer (score -1):

In the above question, the problem is not in the Html or Css.
After a lengthy research I found that the problem was in the bootstrap.Css file. I am using the bootstrap version 5.1.3

Bootstrap classes container and container-fluid are using media rules(@media) and limiting the display area using max-width property. I simply commented the property and run the project then its working perfectly fine.

Adding the bootstrap css section below where I made changes.

```
.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-xxl,
.container-xl,
.container-lg,
.container-md,
.container-sm {
  width: 100%;
/*  padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x, 0.75rem);
*/  /*padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x, 0.75rem);*/
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container-sm, .container {
/*    max-width: 540px;
*/  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-md, .container-sm, .container {
/*    max-width: 720px;
*/  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container {
/*    max-width: 960px;
*/  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container {
/*    max-width: 1140px;
*/  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .container-xxl, .container-xl, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container {
/*    max-width: 1320px;
*/  }
}
```

I don't know what to do in the case of a cdn user and also I don't know is this a good practice. But its gives me exact output what I am expecting.

Appreciating the contributors who spend their time and effort to answer this question.

Thank you.